# How to create sublayout or wrap @RenderBody with fixed HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Some context: I'm currently porting an old .asp site to ASP.NET Core.

While splitting asp pages in layout, ViewComponents and Views, I noticed some common wrapping html pieces shared between some views. I identified three different sublayouts, but i don't want to duplicate the parts in layout that are used on all pages.

From what I know ViewComponents can't render dynamic code inside their tag.

Is there a way to define a thing like this:

_layout

```
<html><head>...</head>
    <body>@RenderSubLayout("_subLayoutName.cshtml")</body>
</html>
```

_subLayoutName.cshtml

```
<div class="outer"> 
    <div class="inner">
         @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

where @RenderBody() renders the view decided by action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layouts are views and view are layouts. It's mostly about how it's used (though there are some functional differences when you use a view as a layout). The point is that just as a view can reference a layout, a layout can likewise reference a layout. For example, you're used to seeing stuff like this:

```
@{ Layout = "_Layout"; }
<!-- my view code -->
```

You can do the same thing with a layout:

```
@{ Layout = "_Layout"; }
@RenderBody()
```

That would be a layout (based on having `RenderBody`, that itself uses a layout, meaning the result of rendering this layout will be dumped into the the specified layout where it calls `RenderBody`.

Based on your example:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

**_SubLayoutName.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "_Layout" }
<div class="outer"> 
    <div class="inner">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

**SomeView.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "_SubLayoutName"; }
<p>This is my view!</p>
```

Would result in:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer"> 
            <div class="inner">
                <p>This is my view!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The one thing you need to keep in mind is that a view can only define sections if they are rendered in its *direct* layout, not some parent. So, for example, if your base layout has `RenderSection("Foo")`, then your sub layout would need to redefine this section, if you want it available to views that use the sub layout. That would be done via:

```
@section Foo
{
    @RenderSection("Foo")
}
```

In other words, you're defining the `Foo` section by actually rendering a `Foo` section. That section, then would be defined by the view, funneling back up to the base layout.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ASP.NET Core, but in .NET framework you can use different Master Pages. Just create couple of different layouts in "~/Views/Shared/"folder and then on each page in header at the top of the page set the layout you need:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml"
}
```

Here is link for example: [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/layouts-master-pages-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-0-part-fourteen/)

Comment: this is just the thing i don't want to do because a major part or resulting layouts will have the same head section and view components. I don't want to duplicate that parts

Comment: Oh, now i see! Well, anyway you already have right answer (by the way, Chris Pratt's answer was useful for me too). Good luck!